# How to upload video on background in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, angular8, angular9

I have an app n which users have to upload its video to complete required items in profile, uploading intro video is a first step, 
I need to know how can i upload video in background as well as user can see its status on toaster/or somewhere, while working on other steps. I have been google all day but haven't found any solution.
My front end is on Angular 8 and python at backend. Deployed on AWS.

Comment: I need to upload video on background while user can enter other information.